# Copy profile data using robocopy with permission

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, copy, robocopy

I'm trying to copy the ChromeData subfolder with permissions that may or may not be inside user profiles. so the folder structure is as follows.

```
-user1
 -chromeData
 -contacts
 -desktop

-user2
 -chromeData
 -contacts
 -desktop
```

the destination should be like this.

```
-user1
 -ChromeData

-user2
 -ChromeData
```

My code is as follows. It does copy the content in the chromeData folder to the destination, but it does not copy the permissions. Please note that I have used /mir /secfix and /copyall with robocopy. None of them worked. I saw a post saying robocopy does not copy inherited permissions. If this is true I need a workaround.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Source=F:\DFSroot\Redirected Content\
set Target=H:\Redirected ChromeData\
rem dir /s /ad /b "%Source%*.*" | find /i "\ChromeData" > C:\Temp\dir.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Temp\dir.txt) do (
set T1=%%a
call set T2=!T1:%Source%=%Target%!
robocopy "%%a" "!T2!" /copyall 
pause
)
```

**UPDATE**

Found that permission is being copied for the chromedata folder but not its parent folder.

Comment: If you resolve this problem, please tell us so.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command **to copy with the ACLs**

```
robocopy "source address" "destination address" *.* /sec
```

Use the following command to **fix an existing tree**.

```
robocopy "source address" "destination address" *.* /secfix /sec
```

[Found this information on this blog](http://yakupkorkmaz.info/?p=12)

Comment: it seems like my code is right afterall. thanks for the answer paul. but i have a new question now. it is updated in the question.could u help me with that?

Comment: @user1844635 what show if you put echo in front of robocopy?

Comment: @user1844635 remove `\\` in the last level of each path